# Print 8 bit binary conversion in java

Tags: java

i'm just trying to make a decimal to binary converter in java, what i want to display is suppose to be like this:

```
Binary 41 is 00101001
```

But, here's display what i just made:

```
Binary 41 is: 101001
```

And here's my code:

```
public void convertBinary(int num){
int binary[] = new int[40];
int index = 0;

while(num > 0){
  binary[index++] = num % 2;
  num/=2;
}
for(int i = index-1; i >= 0; i--){
  System.out.print(binary[i]);
}
```

What can i do, to make a display 8 bit binary? I appreciate it so much for all answer you gave to me, thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pad an integer with zeros on the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integer-with-zeros-on-the-left) (maybe not an exact duplicate, but still).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java convert from decimal to 8-bit binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952307/java-convert-from-decimal-to-8-bit-binary)

Comment: Can you try if (n <= 63)
        {
            for (int i = 8; i >= 0; i--) {
                System.out.print(binary[i]);
            }
        }

Comment: Out of curiosity (and unrelated to your problem), if you need an 8-bit binary number, why are you allocating an array with 40 elements?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
System.out.format("%08d%n", binary[i]);
```

instead of

```
System.out.print(binary[i]);
```

The `"%08d%n"` in `System.out.format("%08d%n", binary[i]);` formats the output as 8 digit integer.

**Note:**
Here are some more examples:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 0):

If `num` is guaranteed to be less than 256, the simplest change for your existing code is to change the loop condition to `index < 8`

```
while(index < 8){
  binary[index++] = num % 2;
  num/=2;
}
```

This directly expresses the desire to have 8 digits.  That is, you simply do not stop when you have converted all non-zero bits.

Answer (score -1):

```
int t;
byte val = 123;

for(t = 128; t > 0; t = t/2){
    if((val & t) != 0) System.out.print("1 ");
    else System.out.print("0 ");
}
```